# Calling an array from one function in another

Tags: python

```
def Data_to_array(filename_and_path):

    r = int
    x, y=[],[]
    data = []
    line_num = 0
    #call data

    P = open(filename_and_path,'r')
    data = P.readlines()
        #Get it to ignore strings
    for line in data:
        line_num += 1
        if line.find("[data]") >= 0:
            r = (line_num+1)
            # Data = P.readlines()[:r]     
            # print (Data)
        if "Sampling Rate" in line:
            SR = float(line[15:])
       
        if "temperature=" in line:
            T = float(line[12:18])
            print(str("Temperature = ")) 
            print(T)
    Data = data[r:line_num] 

    #assign data into dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
    #rename column in data
    df = df.rename(columns = {0: 'volts'})
    #get it to recognise the index
    df.index.name = 'Index'
    #get it to recognise the data as number
    df = df.astype({'volts': float})
    #get index to start at 1
    df.index += 1
    #assign data to lists
    I = df.index.to_list()
    t = df['volts'].to_list()
    #get it to invert data
    y = [element * -1 for element in t]
    #multiply by sampling rate
    x = [element /(SR) for element in I]

def Plot_Data (Data_to_array):
        X,Y = [],[]
        #assign data to X array
        X = Data_to_array.x
        #assign data to Y array
        Y = Data_to_array.y
    #Plot graph
    plt.plot(X,Y)
```

These are my two functions but when running this program  it gives this error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'x'`. I can't see to get it to recognise the data sorted through in the first func. I need the second function because the plotting is going to get more complicated as this work continues.

Comment: Local variables in a function like "x", "y",... here are gone when the function ends. You must either use global variables, return the values, make the functions to methods in a class with instance variables or similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to return X and Y from your function:

```
def Data_to_array(filename_and_path):

    r = int
    x, y=[],[]
    data = []
    line_num = 0
    #call data

    P = open(filename_and_path,'r')
    data = P.readlines()
        #Get it to ignore strings
    for line in data:
        line_num += 1
        if line.find("[data]") >= 0:
            r = (line_num+1)
            # Data = P.readlines()[:r]     
            # print (Data)
        if "Sampling Rate" in line:
            SR = float(line[15:])
       
        if "temperature=" in line:
            T = float(line[12:18])
            print(str("Temperature = ")) 
            print(T)
    Data = data[r:line_num] 

    #assign data into dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
    #rename column in data
    df = df.rename(columns = {0: 'volts'})
    #get it to recognise the index
    df.index.name = 'Index'
    #get it to recognise the data as number
    df = df.astype({'volts': float})
    #get index to start at 1
    df.index += 1
    #assign data to lists
    I = df.index.to_list()
    t = df['volts'].to_list()
    #get it to invert data
    y = [element * -1 for element in t]
    #multiply by sampling rate
    x = [element /(SR) for element in I]
    return x, y

def Plot_Data (filename_and_path):
    #assign data to X array
    X, Y = Data_to_array(filename_and_path)
    #assign data to Y array
    #Plot graph
    plt.plot(X,Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be caused as you have forgotten to return the array from one function and pass it into the other function.

This is a simplified example as to how that should be done:

```
def one():
    array= [1,2,3,4,5]
    return array

def two(array):
    print(array)

array = one()
two(array)
```

This same logic of returning the array and passing it into another function can be used for variables as well as arrays.